# Groovy: what is analogue for java stream anyMatch

Tags: java, groovy, functional-programming, closures, java-stream

What is Groovy analogue for following operation?

```
list.stream().anyMatch(b -> b == 0);
```

Comment: Can you please check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You mean to find if the list contains element `0`?

```
def list = [0,1,2,3,4]
def result = list.any{it == 0}
println result
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/Xcm3Bi)</kbd>

Comment: what if my `list` isn't a list of primitives. But list of objects and I would like to 
filter by property inside?

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ you just change the predicate `{it == 0}`, same thing as with Java Stream API.

Comment: is `it` arbitrary name?

Comment: `it` is not an arbitrary name.  That is the name that the closure parameter gets by default if you don't declare one. `{it == 0}` is the same as `{someArg -> someArg == 0}`.

Comment: "what if my list isn't a list of primitives. But list of objects and I would like to filter by property inside?" - You can do something like `{ it.homeAddress.town == 'St. Louis'}`.

Answer (score 6):

Groovy syntax has a spectrum that ranges from Java-esque to idiomatic Groovy. Both of these work:

```
// Java-esque
List<Integer> list = [4,3,2,1,0]
assert list.stream().any{ b -> b == 0 }

// Groovier (note `it` is an alias for the parameter)
def list2 = [4,3,2,1,0]
assert list2.stream().any{ it == 0 }
```